# Error in Export to excel in the SSRS report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, export-to-excel

I have SSRS reports that I am trying to export to excel format.I am able to do so but on opening one particular report after saving successfully there is an error of missing file(css).
What could be the possible problem and solution?I am stuck only in one report .The rest are working fine.This is the code that am using:

```
 Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.xls";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SkillwiseHeadCount.xls");
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            Response.BinaryWrite(result);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following work for me on a similar project:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
string attachment = "attachment;filename=Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".csv";   
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
```

I used a DataReader.